# separate items with comma in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

template.html

```
{% if leftbar.where_tab.0.location.title or leftbar.report.other_location or leftbar.report.location_description%}
{%with leftbar.where_tab.0.location.title|add:leftbar.report.other_location|add:leftbar.report.location_description as pi%}
{% if pi|length > 36 %}{{pi|slice:"36"}}...{% else  %}{{pi}}{% endif %}
{% endwith %}{%else%}Where{%endif%}
```

I want to make a comma(,) in between the each item.Now it is displaying without any comma its showing all in one line.Need a separater between the item and not at last.

Comment: I don't see a loop here. Where are the multiple items coming from?

Comment: `if` is not a loop. It is a condition check. To achieve what you are looking for you need a template tag. If you try to do it through template it could get very cluttered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a templatetag to achieve what you are looking for:

```
{% load_pi %}
{% display_pi leftbar %}
```

and in the templatetag `pi.py`

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

def display_pi(leftbar):

    title = leftbar.get('where_tab')[0].location.title if leftbar.get('where_tab') and leftbar.get('where_tab')[0].location else ''
    location = leftbar.report.other_location if leftbar.get('report') else ''
    description = leftbar.report.location_description if leftbar.get('report') else ''

    if any([title, location, description]):
        avail = ", ".join([x for x in [title, location, description] if x])
        return (avail[:36] + '..') if len(avail) > 36 else avail
    return "Where"

register.simple_tag(display_pi)
```

Please take care of the error checks more stringently.

Comment: I am getting this error "Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'dict' object has no attribute 'where_tab'" in template i used this line to load templatetag as i am already using that.{% load templatetags %}

Comment: Then modify the template tag appropriately.

Comment: I would highly recommend you learning to debug based on the error message. It clearly says `dict` has not attribute `where_tab' . which means, `leftbar.where_tab` should be `leftbar.get('where_tab')`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33561/discussion-between-monk-l-and-karthikr)